# Literature on Sequence Regresssion

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, recurrent-neural-networks, sequence-modeling, regression

I have some rated time-sequential data and I would like to test if an ANN can learn a correlation between my measurements and ratings.

I suspect I could just try a CNN where 1 Dimension is time or an LSTM/GRU and put the result through sigmoid, but is there any good literature on this? I have been trying to find information on datasets for the problem but it seems that Sequence regression is lacking any big official datasets, even though use-cases are there(e.g. learning personal music taste, try to predict rotten-tomato scores, etc..).

Looking for links to papers describing successful architectures or benchmarks where I can test my models.